# Retornar o numero de uma tabela em um Entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Sou iniciante em python e estou com muita dificuldade em meu código.

Fiz uma tabela onde é inserido uma PRIMARY KEY quando eu aperto em um botão.

Preciso que o último valor gerado nesta tabela retorne em uma "entry" somando + 1 quando aperto outro botão (seria como prever a próxima primary key que será gerada)

Com a função abaixo consigo localizar o valor que quero, porém não sei o que fazer para puxar ela em uma entry

```
def seletc(self):

        self.conecta_db()
        self.select_req = self.cursor.execute("SELECT req FROM req01 ORDER BY req DESC")

        resultado = self.cursor.fetchone()
        print(resultado)

        self.desconecta_db()
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Tenho uma tabela em um banco de dados SQlite, onde possuo a coluna "req", quero que o ultimo valor inserido nesta coluna retorne dentro de uma Entry (Campo digitavel do tkinter) somando + 1.

Comment: Por exemplo: Ultimo valor inserido na coluna "req" foi 10, quero quando eu clique em um botão ele aparece no campo digitavel (Entry) o número 11.

Na função que citei eu consigo fazer um print do valor que estou procurando (o ultimo valor inserido na tabela) porém não consigo retorna-lo em uma entry